# How do I tokenize a char array twice to turn it into a 3D char array?

Tags: c, arrays

I'm quite new in C and I need help. I'd like to tokenize the following char stream twice, first when it meets '|' and then (for every new element in the array) when it meets a space.

For example

```c
input = "command arg | command arg2 | command arg3 arg4"
```

to

```c
commands[0][0] = "command"
commands[0][1] = "arg"

commands[1][0] = "command"
commands[1][1] = "arg2"

commands[2][0] = "command"
commands[2][1] = "arg3"
commands[2][2] = "arg4"
```

I have tried the following:

```
int _pipe(char* input){
    char** commands[MAX_ARGS];
    memcpy(commands, tokenize_pipe(input), sizeof(commands));
    return 1;
}

char*** tokenize_pipe(char* input){

    static char* args[MAX_ARGS];
    static char** args2[MAX_ARGS];

    int args_size = 0;
    int args_size2 = 0;

    char* token = NULL;

    token = strtok(input, "|");

    while(token != NULL) {
        args[args_size] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, "|");
        args_size++;
    }

    args[args_size] = NULL;

    for(int i = 0; i < args_size; i++){

        token = strtok(args[i], " ");

        while(token != NULL) {
            args2[i][args_size2] = token;
            token = strtok(NULL, " ");
            args_size2++;
        }

        args2[i][args_size2] = NULL;
        args_size2 = 0;
    }
    return args2;
}
```

I do not know I can approach this or what to change. I appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: I think you should reset `args_size2` at the start of every iteration of the `for` loop.

Comment: @RuudHelderman thanks I actually removed that by mistake before posting the code. Added it but still with the same segmentation error :(

Comment: `I'm quite new in C` - then don't use stars. Stars are reserved for a [three stars programmers](http://wiki.c2.com/?ThreeStarProgrammer). Don't use them. If you have more then 2 stars - refactor your program. It's easy to loose stars with structures. `struct arg_s { char *str; }; struct cmd_s { struct arg_s *args; size_t cnt; }; struct cmds_s { struct cmd_s *cmd; size_t cnt; }; int tokenize_pipe(struct cmds_s *ret, char *input);`.

Comment: I put a proposal allocating the arrays (and also duplicating the tokens themselves), that avoid to have limitation on the number of commands/arguments and to not use a lot of memory for nothing when there are few, see my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `tokenize_pipe` you do

> ```
>  args2[i][args_size2] = token;
> ```

without initializing `args2[i]`

One way is in `_pipe` to replace

> ```
> char** commands[MAX_ARGS];
> ```

by

```
char* commands[MAX_ARGS][MAX_ARGS];
```

and in `tokenize_pipe` to replace

> static char** args2[MAX_ARGS];

by

```
static char* args2[MAX_ARGS][MAX_ARGS];
```

But of course that uses big arrays, consider to use dynamic arrays, using *malloc* then *realloc* to resize them.

Here a proposal where `tokenize_pipe` return a 3D array where all is allocated, I also duplicate the tokens. NULL is used to indicate the end of the rows and columns

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char*** tokenize_pipe(char* input)
{
  char *** r = malloc(1);
  size_t nCommands = 0;
  char * savePtrCmds;
  char * fullcmd = strtok_r(input, "|", &savePtrCmds);

  while (fullcmd != NULL) {
    char ** tokens = malloc(1);
    size_t nTokens = 0;
    char * token = strtok(fullcmd, " ");

    while (token != 0) {
      tokens = realloc(tokens, (nTokens + 2) * sizeof(char *));
      tokens[nTokens++] = strdup(token); /* also duplicate the token to allows input to disapear */
      token = strtok(NULL, " ");
    }
    tokens[nTokens] = NULL;

    r = realloc(r, (nCommands + 2) * sizeof(char **));
    r[nCommands++] = tokens;
    fullcmd = strtok_r(NULL, "|", &savePtrCmds);
  }

  r[nCommands] = NULL;
  return r;
}

int main()
{
  char *** r;

  {
    char input[] = "command1 arg | command2 arg2 | command3 arg3 arg4";

    r = tokenize_pipe(input);
  }

  /* here input does not exist anymore */

  /* debug */
  for (char *** pcmds = r; *pcmds; ++pcmds) {
    for (char ** pcmd = *pcmds; *pcmd; ++pcmd)
      printf("%s ", *pcmd);
    putchar('\n');
  }

  /* free resources */
  for (char *** pcmds = r; *pcmds; ++pcmds) {
    for (char ** pcmd = *pcmds; *pcmd; ++pcmd)
      free(*pcmd);
    free(*pcmds);
  }
  free(r);

  return 0;
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -Wextra t.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
command1 arg 
command2 arg2 
command3 arg3 arg4
```

Execution under *valgrind* :

```
==7301== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==7301== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==7301== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7301== Command: ./a.out
==7301== 
command1 arg 
command2 arg2 
command3 arg3 arg4 
==7301== 
==7301== HEAP SUMMARY:
==7301==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==7301==   total heap usage: 22 allocs, 22 frees, 1,186 bytes allocated
==7301== 
==7301== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==7301== 
==7301== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7301== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not allocating `args2` memory

```
    args2[i][args_size2] = token;
```

should be

```
 for(...)
 {
    args2[i] = malloc(sizeof(char *)*Some_Length);

    while(token != NULL) {
        args2[i][args_size2] = token;
        token = strtok(NULL, " ");
        args_size2++;
    }
  }
```

Also
 It is not a good idea to do pointer assignment as below since `input` string can change at some point of time.

```
    args2[i][args_size2] = token;
```

instead

```
    args2[i][args_size2] = strdup(token);
```